# Is authenticity(csrf) token sent with html form tag in Rails 2

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, csrf, ruby-on-rails-2, csrf-protection

I have a task where I need to take care of verifying `csrf` tokens in a Rails 2 application.

I have given `protect_from_forgery` in `application_controller.rb`.
Now in my application, most of the places I am using html form instead of rails

```
<%form_tag%>
```

Question is :

Rails `<%form_tag%>` by default sends the authenticity token.

Will html `form` tag also do this? Or I will have to add a hidden authenticity token field manually at all those places where I am using `<html>`?

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite all forms to `form_tag`.

Also you can just insert authenticity token into the form yourself. Something like this:

```
<form action=... >
  <%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token %>
  ... rest of your form ...
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I will have to manually add the token.

Answer (score 0):

I think the recommendation is to use <% form_tag %> as they attached the authenticity token hidden_field. If not, you will need to manually add the hidden field if you are using the html form tag.

My suggestion is to change all to using the form_tag and let rails handle the rest. A bit of pain now will save you a lot of code debts in the future.

Comment: So...is it that html form wont send authenticity token ?

Comment: Yes, that the reason for the form_tag, its suppose to help you build the authenticity token hidden field automatically.